# exponential integration in terms of incomplete gamma function

Tags: calculus, integration, gamma-function

I am stuck with integrating the following expression:

\begin{equation}
I=\int_{a}^{\infty} x^{d-1} {\rm e}^{-(bx+c/x)}\,
{\rm d}x.
\end{equation}

Can it be expressed in terms of incomplete gamma function, which is defined as
\begin{equation}
\Gamma(d,a)=\int_{a}^{\infty} x^{d-1} {\rm e}^{-x}\,
{\rm d}x.
\end{equation}

Else, how do I proceed with the integration?

Comment: Is the exponent $\frac{-bx-c}{x}$ or $-bx-\frac{c}{x}$?

Comment: It is an incomplete version of the [modified Bessel function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E10).

Comment: @Hersh the exponent is -bx-c/x

Comment: @Gary can you please elaborate?

Comment: There is not much I can elaborate. Just look at the two integrals.